# SVG, Vue: If 'viewBox' is reactive scaling doesnt work. Why?

Tags: vue.js, svg

```
<svg width=300px height=75px viewbox="0 0 450 100">...</svg>   //  It works. Scaling of the viewbox to 300px is OK.
<svg width=300px height=75px :viewbox="viewbox">...</svg>      //  All the same, but 'viewbox' is reactive property. Scaling doesnt work.
<svg width=300px height=75px :viewbox="'0 0 450 100'">...</svg>   //  Doesnt work too
```

viewbox = '0 0 450 100' — Vue data property

Try here: https://jsfiddle.net/y0zgefs8/

Comment: Please add an [Minimal minimal-reproducible-example StackOverflow Snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to your post. It will help readers execute your code with one click. And help create answers with one click. See [How to add a StackOverflow snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers)

Comment: Sandbox is on the jsfiddle.

Comment: Then you guarantee that fiddle will always be there... if in 10 years time that link no longer works, StackOverflow will strip you of all your points.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

Use *:view-box.camel* instead *:viewbox*